# SWT: make a mouse event propagate through stacked composites

Tags: java, events, swt, mouseevent, composite

This sounds easy, but I couldn't find a clue.

I have two `Composite`s, one (small) above the other (big), absolutely positioned. When I click on the above `Composite`, I need it to be *transparent* to the event, because it should be caught by the below `Composite`.

The only possible solution I came up with is associating the same `MouseListener` to both the `Composite`s and add logic to discriminate. But I would be much easier if the below `Composite` could receive the event as it was originated on it.

Comment: _as it was originated on it_: How would the gui know, that the event is for the composite **behind** another composite?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm asking: can we make an event-trasparent composite, or make one behave that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the event is associated with the source of event, i.e. widget. You cannot substitute one widget onto another widget. If you want that another widget receive that event, you should make that event occurred there. This could be done if you create the event manually and do either widget's `notifyListeners` or display's `post` that event.